# Merge two set of array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to merge two objects fetched from response distance matrix api into one. Distance matrix api can't accept more than 25 set of lat and long data. Hence with the help of for loop i am trying to run the distance matrix api multiple times and merge the results, so that it can be used.

```
let distanceMatrixData = [];
let countk = 0;
for(let k = 0; k<destlatlongArr.length; k++ ){

    Request.get(
      `${gmapBaseUrl}/distancematrix/json?origins=${custlatlong}&destinations=${destlatlongArr[k]}&key=${process.env.googleMapsKey}`,
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            error: error,
            message: "Error in distance matrix Api",
          });
        }

        console.log("Response of Distance Matrix Api is below : ");
        distanceMatrixData = JSON.parse(body).rows[0]; //this always gives with 2nd iteration data . I also tried distanceMatrixData.push(JSON.parse(body).rows[0]); but it would create two different set of data


        countk++;
        
        if(countk == destlatlongArr.length){
            console.log(distanceMatrixData);
        }
    });
}
```

I have destlatlongArr.length as 2 and it can be even more in future.
I wanted the data in JSON.parse(body).rows[0] to always be filled in distanceMatrixData Array.

1st set of data in JSON.parse(body).rows[0] is below :

```
{
  elements: [
    {
      distance: {
        text: "2 m",
        value: 2,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "2 min",
        value: 2,
      },
      status: "OK",
    },
    {
      distance: {
        text: "3 m",
        value: 3,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "3 min",
        value: 3,
      },
      status: "OK",
    }
  ],
}
```

Second set of data in JSON.parse(body).rows[0] is below:

```
{
  elements: [
    {
      distance: {
        text: "4 m",
        value: 4,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "4 min",
        value: 4,
      },
      status: "OK",
    },
    {
      distance: {
        text: "4 m",
        value: 4,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "4 min",
        value: 4,
      },
      status: "OK",
    }
  ],
}
```

I want two data merged in distanceMatrixData  as below (also all the objects in elements from both iteration to be merged to elements of distanceMatrixData so that i get the merged data)  :

```
{
  elements: [
    {
      distance: {
        text: "2 m",
        value: 2,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "2 min",
        value: 2,
      },
      status: "OK",
    },
    {
      distance: {
        text: "3 m",
        value: 3,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "3 min",
        value: 3,
      },
      status: "OK",
    },
        {
      distance: {
        text: "4 m",
        value: 4,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "4 min",
        value: 4,
      },
      status: "OK",
    },
    {
      distance: {
        text: "4 m",
        value: 4,
      },
      duration: {
        text: "4 min",
        value: 4,
      },
      status: "OK",
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have gone through your problem here is the solution. use spread
> operator to merge array.

```
let distanceMatrixData = [];
let countk = 0;
for(let k = 0; k<destlatlongArr.length; k++ ){

    Request.get(
      `${gmapBaseUrl}/distancematrix/json?origins=${custlatlong}&destinations=${destlatlongArr[k]}&key=${process.env.googleMapsKey}`,
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            error: error,
            message: "Error in distance matrix Api",
          });
        }

        console.log("Response of Distance Matrix Api is below : ");
        distanceMatrixData = [...distanceMatrixData, ...JSON.parse(body).rows[0]];


        countk++;
        
        if(countk == destlatlongArr.length){
            console.log(distanceMatrixData);
        }
    });
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is not gonna workout for me, see the expected response which i needed.

Comment: Actually somewhat your answer helped me
distanceMatrixObj.elements = [...distanceMatrixObj.elements, ...JSON.parse(body).rows[0].elements];